# Selecting Any Row in MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a product page and would like to be able to select which MySQL result I am referencing.

For example, I would like to be able to reference the result in row 5 without having to do a loop to get to row 5. As well as still be able to access all the rows before that later on. At first, I was thinking of `something $row['result'][4]` to get just row 5 but realized that would return the 5th character in the first rows' result column.

Is there any good way of going about this so I can just access any row at will without having to play around with loops and re-querying the database to reset where I am at in the result?

**EDIT:**
The most basic query I am using is `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 25`
so it returns 25 rows. I would like to be able to get, for example, the 5th row in that list of 25 without having to use `fetch_assoc()` 5 times or limiting my query to just 1 row with an offset of 5.

**EDIT 2:**
Thank you everyone for your help, I have gotten the answer courtesy of Jakupov whose response is selected as this questions answer.

Comment: Please describe more when you need to access your result set in this way.  MySQL has `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` capabilities, which might be what you are looking for (or maybe not).

Comment: Please specify the version of MySQL. Recently version 8 has been released and this version supports `row_number() over(...)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen know that is a possible way to go about it, but that would use up a lot of resources since I would have the query the database several times while generating the page. This page is dynamic, so I am calling a page that is located on the server using XMLHttpRequest to call that page and post the results to the current page. I am hoping there is something just as simple and telling the script to look straight at the specific row out of all the results. I hope that makes sense. It would be like using result[1][0] in javascript to get the first column in row 2,

Comment: @Used_By_Already the server is running MySQL version 10.1.36-MariaDB-cll-lve according to the server information menu.

Comment: How do you expect the database to know which row you are talking about? What makes "row 5" row 5?

Comment: Can you add an existing query to the question and explain **what order** the row numbering should use (this is - as others have pointed out - **essential**)

Comment: @Used_By_Already I have edited my original question with the query and a bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) may help you to fetch all rows at once.

If you cannot use fetch_all(), you can still use fetch_assoc() cycle just once:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows[4]);
```

Comment: Although that probably would have worked, it does not seem that I can use it on the server I am working on. Thank you for offering that up though as it has given me some other options to look at.

Comment: @saxon564 why wouldn't it work. It seems thats what you want. +1

Comment: I updated answer for "only fetch_assoc" option. If you don't use fetch_all, you have to use fetch_assoc through result at least once.

Comment: @madhur Bhaiya Note that my comment was before his edit which contained the while loop, therefore it was directed at the fetch_all() method, which the server I am on doesnt seem to have the supporting script for. When I have the opportunity, I plan on trying the while loop he shared.

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense.  Rows in a mySql table have no intrinsic "order", unless your query has an explicit `order by` clause.

What you *can* do is read each row into a PHP array, then randomly access each array element any time you want, in any order you want.

If you happen to be using MySQLi, then [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) might be ideal for you.

Comment: If there is no order in a mySql table, then how would the OFFSET clause be able to work there must be some order is uses to do that. I do not get how with what is essentially an array of array (Yes I know it is not that simple,)  you cannot define the row in which you are reading in the result.I currently have $list = $result->fetch_assoc(); my issue with this, it is only selects the "top" row and essentially removes the row it just selected. Because of this, if I want to go back to that row, then I have to requery the database.

Comment: There is no intrinsic "logical" order.  In other words, a "select" query with no "order by" does not retrieve the rows in any particular order. You have to have an "order by" in your SQL query to get an "order" in the result set.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. I am actually using the ORDER BY clause for this query. I have edited my original question to show the most basic query I will have for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain, but you may actually be looking for `$row[4]['result']`, *not* `$row['result'][4]`;

I suggest you run `print_r($row)` to see what the actual array structure looks like and work it from there.

This is assuming of course that you've retrieved more than one row in the query, the way some frameworks do it. If it's a traditional fetch where you retrieve one row at a time, and you do not wish to fetch the first 4 rows, then you need some other mechanism to query the database in such a way as to retrieve what is logically "Row 5".

Probably the simplest example is an integer primary key (e.g., "id") with auto_increment. Then it's a simple matter to add "where id = 5" to your query.

Comment: Unfortunately I did try that as well ($row[4]['result']) and it returned nothing. Presumably because it was looking for a column that was named the number I tried with.

Comment: I do not know the structure of your table, but clearly for this to work, you need a column named "id" and it has to be the Primary Key of the table, and it has to be an Integer, and it has to have Auto_Increment, and Row 5 has to have *not* been Deleted.

Comment: In regards to your edit, that is what I am trying not to do, as I don't want to have the query the database more than I have too to make this work. If in the end that is literally the only way, then I will, but I want to exhaust all other possible options first.

Comment: Taking a second look at the question, it appears you're loading 25 rows into memory. That brings me back to using `print_r($row)` so you can find out the actual array structure of the data being returned.

Comment: General convention is that `$row` is one row fetched during while loop. OP need to fetchAll at once into (let's say) `$rows`. And then, access the 5th row using `$rows[4]`. @saxon564

Comment: Thank you @Madhur Bhaiya that is exactly what I am wanting to do.

Comment: @UncaAlby If I use that on the result I get a mysqli object, if I use that after the fetch_assoc() I get a single row array.